# Does the association $V \mapsto GL(V)$ define a functor?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, linear-transformations, general-linear-group

As is stated in the title:

> **Question:** for $k$ a field, does there exist a functor $F: k$-$\mathrm{v.s.} \to \mathrm{Grp}$ which on objects is $V \mapsto GL(V)$?

My guess is no, because it doesn't look to me like there's a sensible way to map the morphisms. However, I can't come up with a counterexample in a similar way to Arturo Magidin in [Why is there no functor $\mathsf{Group}\to\mathsf{AbGroup}$ sending groups to their centers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158438/why-is-there-no-functor-mathsfgroup-to-mathsfabgroup-sending-groups-to-th).

Here is my attempt at imitating his answer: take $f: k \to k^2$, $f = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $g: k^2 \to k$, $g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $g \circ f = 1_k$, so $F(f):k^{\times} \to GL_2(k)$ is injective and $F(g): GL_2(k) \to k^\times$ is surjective. On the other hand, $f \circ g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, but this doesn't really give me anything.

Comment: Generally taking automorphisms is only “naturally” functorial with respect to isomorphisms. It would be interesting to rule out “non-natural” functors also, I guess.

Comment: Yep. The only thing I could think of for morphisms would be $f: V \to W \mapsto f_*:GL(V) \to GL(W)$, $f_*(A) = f \circ A$, but obviously $f$ can be anything and so $f \circ A$ isn't necessarily an isomorphism. Is this what you meant by your remark?

Comment: That doesn’t produce another map from $W$ to $W$; you need to also precompose with the inverse of $f$ which need not exist.

Comment: True! Even more reason to believe such a functor doesn't exist.

Comment: The "natural" functor with respect to isomorphisms that Qiaochu alludes to sends an isomorphism $f:V\to W$ to the conjugation by $f$ map $GL(V)\to GL(W)$.  Any "natural" functor with respect to all morphisms ought to extend this, i.e. be given by conjugation on isomorphisms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(**Edit 3:** The first argument I found is long but there's a shorter argument below it.)

Let's complete Eric's nice argument. First I'll say the first thing he said in a little more detail, which is also what Arturo used. In any category, a [**retract**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)) of an object $c$ is an object $d$ together with two morphisms $f : c \to d, g : d \to c$ such that $fg = \text{id}_d$. This means $f$ is a [split epimorphism](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/split-epimorphisms-and-split-monomorphisms/) and $g$ is a split monomorphism. Retracts are the "particularly nice subobjects" (which are also simultaneously quotients); e.g. in an additive category they are precisely the direct summands. The significance of retracts for our purposes is that

- retracts are preserved by arbitrary functors, and
- in $\text{Vect}$, $k^n$ is a retract of $k^m$ iff $n \le m$.

So if $V \mapsto GL(V)$ were a functor, this would imply in particular that $GL_n(k)$ is a retract of $GL_m(k)$ whenever $n \le m$. (Incidentally, for groups retracts correspond exactly to semidirect product decompositions.) So, suppose $f : GL_m(k) \to GL_n(k)$ is an epi and $3 \le n \le m$. [It's known](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group_is_perfect) that when $m \ge 3$ the subgroup $SL_m(k)$ is [perfect](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfect_group), so its image in $GL_n(k)$ must also be perfect and hence must land in $SL_n(k)$. So $f$ induces an epi $SL_m(k) \to SL_n(k)$. An epi maps centers to centers, so $f$ induces an epi $PSL_m(k) \to PSL_n(k)$.

[It's also known](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group_is_simple) that when $m \ge 3$, $PSL_m(k)$ is simple. So $f$ is an epi between two nontrivial simple groups, which therefore must be an isomorphism. In other words, we've proven:

> **Claim:** if $V \mapsto GL(V)$ is a functor, then for $3 \le n \le m$, the groups $PSL_n(k)$ and $PSL_m(k)$ are isomorphic.

So it suffices to disprove this.

---

**Edit #2:** Okay, I think I can *actually* complete the argument now. The following weaker result suffices:

> **Proposition:** There exist positive integers $3 \le n < m$ such that $PSL_n(k) \not\simeq PSL_m(k)$.

*Proof.* We'll proceed by finding $3 \le n < m$ and a nonabelian finite simple group $G$ that embeds into $PSL_m(k)$ but not $PSL_n(k)$. By simplicity, if such a group $G$ embeds into $GL_m(k)$ then any such embedding has image in $SL_m(k)$, and by simplicity again it also embeds into $PSL_m(k)$. Hence if we take $m$ to be the smallest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G$ (which is necessarily faithful) then $G$ embeds into $PSL_m(k)$.

On the other hand, $PSL_n(k)$ acts by conjugation on $\mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$ (the vector space of traceless $n \times n$ matrices), which has dimension $n^2 - 1$ over $k$, so if $G$ embeds into $PSL_n(k)$ then it embeds into $GL_{n^2 - 1}(k)$. Hence if we take $n$ to be such that $n^2 - 1$ is less than the smallest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G$ over $k$, then $G$ does not embed into $GL_{n^2-1}(k)$ and so does not embed into $PSL_n(k)$.

Now it suffices to find a nonabelian finite simple group $G$ such that the smallest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G$ over $k$ is at least $9$ (which means we can take $n = 3$ and $m$ the dimension of this irrep). At this point we'll want to say something about the extent to which this problem is independent of the choice of $k$.

**Case 1:** $\text{char}(k) = 0$. Any embedding $\rho : G \to GL_d(k)$ of a finite group $G$ into $GL_d(k)$ has image lying in $GL_d(R)$ where $R$ is the $\mathbb{Q}$-subalgebra of $k$ generated by the matrix entries of $\rho(g), g \in G$; since $G$ is finite $R$ is finitely generated, and then by the Nullstellensatz $R$ has a maximal ideal $M$ such that $R/M$ is a number field (a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$). By simplicity $G$ also embeds into $GL_d(R/M)$. In other words, the smallest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G$ over an arbitrary field $k$ of characteristic zero is bounded from below by the smallest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G$ over a number field, which is in turn bounded from below by (and is in fact equal to) the smallest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$. So the characteristic zero case reduces to the case $k = \mathbb{C}$.

At this point we can appeal to standard results; for example [it's known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574456/groups-with-no-small-nontrivial-representation) that for $n \ge 7$ the alternating group $A_n$ has no nontrivial representations over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $\le n-2$. I don't know how to prove this off the top of my head but I think it shouldn't be too hard to at least get a bound of $\le \frac{n-2}{2}$ using standard facts about the representation theory of $S_n$, which would suffice for our purposes.

Explicitly, it follows that $A_{10}$ doesn't embed into $GL_8(\mathbb{C})$ and hence doesn't embed into $PSL_3(k)$, and since it does embed into $PSL_9(k)$ it follows that $PSL_3(k) \not\simeq PSL_9(k)$.

**Case 2:** $\text{char}(k) = p$ is positive. Repeating the same construction as above, any embedding $\rho : G \to GL_d(k)$ has image lying in $GL_d(R)$ where $R$ is now the $\mathbb{F}_p$-subalgebra of $k$ generated by the matrix entries of $\rho(g), g \in G$. The Nullstellensatz gives that $R$ has a maximal ideal $M$ such that $R/M$ is a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ for some $q = p^i$, and we get an embedding $G \to GL_d(\mathbb{F}_q)$. So the characteristic $p$ case reduces to the case $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

In this case we can argue as follows. $GL_d(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup given by the unipotent subgroup $U_d(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of upper triangular matrices with diagonal entries $1$. This group is nilpotent of [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group#Definition) $d-1$, hence all of its subgroups have nilpotency class $\le d-1$. So if $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup of nilpotency class $\ge d$ then it can't embed into $GL_d(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Now it suffices to take $G = PSL_{d+1}(\mathbb{F}_p)$, whose Sylow $p$-subgroup is $U_{d+1}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ (since it lies in the kernel of the determinant map and also has trivial intersection with the center of $SL_{d+1}(\mathbb{F}_p)$).

Explicitly, it follows that $PSL_9(\mathbb{F}_p)$ doesn't embed into $GL_8(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$ and hence doesn't embed into $PSL_3(k)$, and since it does embed into $PSL_9(k)$ it follows that $PSL_3(k) \not\simeq PSL_9(k)$.  $\Box$

(There's probably a cleaner way to do this...)

---

**Edit 3:** There is! We'll show that no functor $F : \text{Vect} \to \text{Grp}$ sending $V$ to $GL(V)$ can exist by using functoriality a bit more.

First, writing $0$ for the zero-dimensional vector space, we have $GL(0) = 1$ (the trivial group). It follows that the zero linear transformation $0 : V \to W$ between any two vector spaces, which factors through $0$, is trivial, since the induced map $F(V) \to F(0) \to F(W)$ factors through the trivial group.

Now consider a short exact sequence $0 \to k^n \to k^{n+m} \to k^m \to 0$ (for example, given by the inclusion of the first $n$ coordinates, and the projection to the last $m$ coordinates). Applying $F$ produces a sequence

$$GL_n(k) \xrightarrow{f} GL_{n+m}(k) \xrightarrow{g} GL_m(k)$$

where $f$ is a split monomorphism, hence in particular injective, and $g$ is a split epimorphism, hence in particular surjective, and $gf$ is trivial. For $n, m \ge 3$ the same conditions hold after passing to commutator subgroups, so we get a sequence

$$SL_n(k) \xrightarrow{f} SL_{n+m}(k) \xrightarrow{g} SL_m(k)$$

where, again, $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective and $gf$ is trivial. $\text{ker}(g)$ must therefore be a normal subgroup $N$ of $SL_{n+m}(k)$ such that both $N$ and the quotient by $N$ are nonabelian. But by the simplicity of $PSL_{n+m}(k)$ (here $n, m \ge 3$ so $n+m \ge 6$), the only proper normal subgroups of $SL_{n+m}(k)$ are subgroups of its center, which are abelian; contradiction. So no such sequence exists.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the amazing answer! One question about the $k$ infinite case - how do you define $SL_m(k)$ and $PSL_m(k)$ for $m$ infinite and are they also perfect/simple in that case?

Comment: @Matija: ah, you’re right, that’s a big gap. Of course we can’t define the determinant anymore. It should still be possible to write down a simple group related to $GL_n$ but I don’t know what it is anymore off the top of my head...

Comment: @Matija: okay, so the "obvious" conjecture is that if $V$ is a countable-dimensional vector space then the quotient $GL(V) / GL_{\text{fin}}(V)$ of $GL(V)$ by the subgroup of automorphisms fixing a subspace of finite codimension is simple. The analogous result for permutations of a countable set is known: https://mathoverflow.net/a/12307/290 But I haven't found a reference stating or proving the linear version.

Comment: Ah, sorry, we need to further quotient by the center. So $PGL(V) / PGL_{\text{fin}}(V)$ or something like that.

Comment: @Matija: okay, I fixed the argument, we don't need to consider the infinite-dimensional case anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, I finally had the time to go through the answer and accept it. Thanks so much, it was a great opportunity and pleasure for me to learn some group theory while trying to understand this!

Comment: @Matija: you're very welcome, and thanks for asking the nice question!

Answer (score 8):

No such functor exists in general.  Note that if $n\geq m$, then $k^m$ is a retract of $k^n$, so if such a functor existed, then $GL_m(k)$ would have to be a retract of $GL_n(k)$.  I suspect this is basically never true for $n>m>1$, though I don't know a proof for general $k$.  In particular, when $k=\mathbb{F}_2$, the group $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is simple for all $n>2$, so it has no nontrivial retracts, so such a functor definitely cannot exist for $k=\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: This should at least work when $k$ is finite and I think it always works: $GL_n(k)$ has a Jordan-Holder decomposition in which the only nonabelian simple group is $PSL_n(k)$ (except for a small list of exceptions where this group isn't simple), and (I think) these are nonisomorphic for $n \neq m$.